# Can I use nginX+Webkit+PHP+SQLite to create Mac Appstore applications?

Tags: php, macos, webkit, nginx, app-store

I want do develop for Mac Appstore using Laravel PHP. Is there any framework that contains Nginx, Webkit and Sqlite, and if there is no such framework, how easy it is to create one?
I am aware of tidesdk.org but will not help me to develop using Laravelphp framework.

Update: i am not asking about iOS, i just want to develop for OS X.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to build native iOS applications with PHP. No sane one at least

Comment: thanks, but I am not asking about ios my question is about osx, by the way there is a framework to build for ios using php by adobe , it is called flex flash builder, but it is very ugly

Comment: Oh, sorry. You meant OS X. I *think* the same applies there. PHP is not really the right platform for developing desktop apps, even though there are workarounds. I'd recommend learning the right language / platform instead that is dominant on the target OS.

Comment: There is a desktop extension for a local PHP install, though I am not sure how active development is, or whether it runs on OS X. Worth some research though: http://gtk.php.net and also http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/tutorials.installation.macosx-stepbystep.php

Comment: Why not build one using javascript? You could use `mosync` and other frameworks..

Comment: Why not use XCode + Objective-c + Webkit + Core Data (SQLite)

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches for this:

1) With building a full blown application in just PHP, there is a framework called [miniPHP](http://exvision.net/miniphp/). It's the only thing I could find for OS X, other than [WinBinder](http://winbinder.org/) (windows only).

2) Build a web based application and embed it in a [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The OS X GUI would be in Objective C, but the meat of the application would be on the server.

I personally feel option #1 is a bad idea because PHP isn't designed to run as an instance application. It's better used for web applications or command line scripts.

Option #2 is your best option. I believe the WebView has bindings with JavaScript to make calls to/from the GUI application. I personally haven't used WebView, so I'm not sure how that works. I mostly develop on iOS, and the UIWebView is limited by comparison.

Comment: I suspect Apple wouldn't allow an app on the app store where the bulk of the functionality goes through a web view and resides on a remote server (i.e. security / hack risk).

Comment: That isn't true. They are more strict with iOS and many apps have their core functionality in a web view. Asana and Wells Fargo, just to name a couple. Mac App Store apps are also sandboxed, and you can ensure the web view stays on your domain. The web view is also no more or less secure than Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, you can't.

PHP is a back-end language. Though you can use the Webkit engine in OSX to run your app, the GUI of your app should be write in Javascript and HTML. You can search google with "HTML5 native app" to get more information.

As for Nginx, it is a server program. It serves for server but not client. Anyone who wants to build an app in Mac Store or Google Play or whatever should not involve Nginx.

SQLite can be helpful in native app development, I think you could use SQLite with some form of API that the framework you use providing.

To get more info, see PhoneGap and Node-webkit, they could help you assuming you are a web developer. And if you plan to develop on OSX, the recommend way is Objective-c Language and Cocoa Framework and Xcode IDE.

Comment: You mention: "Anyone who wants to build an app in Mac Store or Google Play or whatever should not involve Nginx". Why? Is Apple going to reject such app?

Comment: Nope. But seems this is very unnecessary.